# How do I solve this system of modular equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

How do I solve this system of modular equations?

$2=(4+6a)k_1^{-1}\bmod19 $

$11=(3+6b)k_1^{-1}\bmod19$

$8=(5+5a)k_2^{-1}\bmod19$

$6=(18+5b)k_2^{-1}\bmod19$

I want to get the values for $a, b, k_1$, and $k_2$. Note that $k^{-1}$ denotes the modular inverse (mod $19$) of $k$.

How do I solve this? Or are there infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Clearing denoms (scaling by $k_i)$ yields a system of linear equations in $\,a,b,k_1,k_2$ over the *field* $\Bbb Z_{19}$. You can solve it the same way as over amy field, e.g. by triangularization or Gaussian elimination..

Answer (score 0):

Multiply all congruences by $k_1$ or $k_2$ as appropriate. This gives a linear system:
$$2k_1=4+6a\bmod19$$
$$11k_1=3+6b\bmod19$$
$$8k_2=5+5a\bmod19$$
$$6k_2=18+5b\bmod19$$
Now $19$ is a prime number, so we can solve this as if it were over $\mathbb Q$, treating all divisions as multiplications by inverses. We get the following set of solutions (modulo $19$ of course):
$$(k_1,k_2,a,b)=(5,6,1,15)+(4,4,14,1)t\qquad t\in\mathbb Z;k_1,k_2\ne0$$

Answer (score 0):

Solving in pari/gp.

Find $k_1$:

`(4+6*a)/Mod(2,19)`=`Mod(3, 19)*a + Mod(2, 19)`

and

`(3+6*b)/Mod(11,19)`=`Mod(4, 19)*b + Mod(2, 19)`

i.e. $k_1\equiv 2+3a\equiv 2+4b \pmod{19}$

Find $k_2$:

`(5+5*a)/Mod(8,19)`=`Mod(3, 19)*a + Mod(3, 19)`

and

`(18+5*b)/Mod(6,19)`=`Mod(4, 19)*b + Mod(3, 19)`

i.e. $k_2\equiv 3+3a\equiv 3+4b \pmod{19}$

Find $a$ from $3a\equiv 4b \pmod{19}$

`4*b/Mod(3,19)`=`Mod(14, 19)*b`

i.e. $a\equiv 14b \pmod{19}$

Thus $(k_1,k_2,a,b) \equiv (2,3,0,0) + (4b,4b,14b,b) \pmod{19}$

Verify in W.Mathematica:

`Solve[{2*k1==4+6*a,11*k1==3+6*b,8*k2==5+5*a,6*k2==18+5*b},{k1,k2,a,b},Modulus->19]/.C[1]->b`=

`{{k1 -> 2 + 4 b, k2 -> 3 + 4 b, a -> 14 b, b -> b}}`

Comment: Understood. Now, if I know the exact value of b, can I find a single unique solution to these equations?